# Is it possible to register same interface via SimpleIoC twice?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, ioc-container

Assume that I have following Service:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
     public ServiceA(IBuffer bufferA, IBuffer bufferB) 
    {
        ;//
    }
}
```

Is it possible to register same interface twice?

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new Buffer());
SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => new Buffer());
```

I know that I can register IServiceA as:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceA>(() => new ServiceA(new Buffer(), new Buffer()));
```

I would prefere the other way:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceA>();
```

but in above example I got exception since it is imposible to register same Interface twice.

Do you know another way to register same interface twice via simpleIoC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt you can do the following with any container

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceA>();
```

`IServiceA` is an interface, an abstraction. When you register an abstraction you need to provide a concrete implementation of that abstraction. The container cannot guess the implementation you expect it to provide when you ask for an instance of `IServiceA`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at named registrations.

Reading through the SimpleIoc documentation [here](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/e2774a68-2132-6ab6-61a4-2eb3e8ae811b.htm)

You will need to register you IBuffer implementations with a key. Then instruct SimpleIoc to resolve them using that key.

Look at the 4th and 5th example on this [link](http://www.guruumeditation.net/en/ioc-and-di-with-mvvm-light/)

Comment: thanks, this examples are correct but event with them I still cannot register my service like this: SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceA>();

Comment: There's no way for the IOC framework to know which implementation you want it to use in this case unless you explicitly tell it? Question is, why does it matter which way you do the registration?

Comment: I asked because it matter in case of simlicity. It is simpler to register like this SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceA>(); than SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IServiceA>(() => new ServiceA(buffer1, buffer2, otherSth1, otherSth2, othersth3));